# MaskMoney.js not working on Dynamic add Field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have some problem about dynamic add field combaine MaskMoney,

> HTML part

```
<div class='table-responsive mailbox-messages'>

             <table id="dataTable" class='table table-hover'>
             <tr>
                <th>Keperluan</th>
                  <th>Tanggal Transaksi</th>
                <th>Total Transaksi</th>
                <th>Keterangan</th>
                  <th>Scan Foto</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
                <tbody class="input_fields_wrap">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="perlu'+x+'" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Keperluan"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mytexts[]" id="s" class="form-control tgl" required="required" placeholder="Tanggal Transaksi"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="mytexts[]" id="demo1" class="form-control numeric "  required="required" placeholder="Only Number"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mytexts[]" id="s" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Keterangan"/></td>
                  <td><input type="file" name="mytexts[]" id="s" class="small" required="required"/></td>
                  <td><button class="add_field_button btn btn-success">Add Field</button></td>


          </tr>


                </tbody>
             </table>
 </div>
```

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
     var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
     var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
     var x = 1; //initlal text box count
     $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
         if(x < max_fields){ 
             x++; //text box increment
            i = $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="perlu'+x+'" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Keperluan"/></td><td><input type="text" name="mytexts[]" id="s" class="form-control tgl" required="required" placeholder="Tanggal Transaksi"/></td><td><input type="text" name="mytexts[]" id="demo'+x+'" class="form-control numeric" required="required" placeholder="Only Number" /></td><td><input type="text" name="mytexts[]" id="s" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Keterangan"/></td><td><input type="file" name="mytexts[]" id="s" class="small" required="required"/></td><td><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-danger">Remove</a></td></tr>');
             //re-init mask money to apply new added input 
            $(wrapper).append(i); //add input box

         }


    });


$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("tr").remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });



});

$("#demo1").maskMoney({prefix:'Rp ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: false});
```

The running snippet of my code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kangtupit/xhgtrpcm/)

The problem on Field "Total Transaksi", MaskMoney Notworking,

first field work fine but when button Add new Field = NOT WORK.

I've searched on internet but the answer is still eluding me.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ofri, there is no code in your pastebin ... -> https:// jsfiddle.net/kangtupit/xhgtrpcm/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kangtupit/xhgtrpcm/    may be you can cek again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `maskMoney()` method, you run it only once; at the beginning of your page load. After that, other new fields don't have the binding that `maskMoney()` provides. You will either need to rebind to each new set of elements or use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). It doesn't look like the `maskMoney` plugin has a feature to delegate, so you can rebind on the creation of each button:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmj3ryer/1/

Comment: sebelumnya saya sudah mencoba tapi gagal, tapi terimakasih sudah membantu saya. kode anda berjalan bagus. sempurna. SOLVED

Comment: Glad I could help :)